# spliting column value through 2 columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a the below dataset:

```
timestamp   converationId   UserId  MessageId       tpMessage   Message 
1614578324  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef 5bbd34859329    question    Where do you live?
1614578881  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef d3b5d3884152    answer      Brooklyn
1614583764  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef 0e4501fcd61f    question    What's your name?
1614590885  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef 97d841b79ff7    answer      Phill
1614594952  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef 11ed3fd24767    question    What's your gender?
1614602036  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef 601538860004    answer      Male
1614602581  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef 8bc8d9089609    question    How old are you?
1614606219  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef a2bd45e64b7c    answer      35
```

and I want to split the timestap column, one is the timestamp for the question and the other is the time stampe for the answer

for that I'm creating a new table with the case statement below(step 2):

```
case when tpMessage = 'question' 
    then timestamp
    end  ts_question
,case when tpMessage = 'answer'
    then ts_timestamp
    end  ts_answer
```

with that, I tried many different forms of inner join and left join ,but didn't manage to get the result I want, which is the below:

```
ts_question ts_answer   converationId   UserId
1614578324  1614578881  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef
1614583764  1614590885  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef
1614594952  1614602036  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef
1614602581  1614606219  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef
```

with that key in hand, I would be able to go to my first table and get the the message column and turn it in 2 new columns, question and answer, my final outuput would be
:

```
ts_question ts_answer   converationId   UserId      Question            Answer
1614578324  1614578881  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef     What's your name?   Phill   
1614583764  1614590885  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef     Where do you live?  Brooklyn
1614594952  1614602036  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef     How old are you?    35  
1614602581  1614606219  ceb9004ae9d3    1c376ef     What's your gender? Male
```

I would be satisfied you guys could help me to get the step 2 done.

thanks

Comment: What if there are two consecutive questions, or answers?

Comment: hey @GMB thanks for your reply, it can't happen, I can have consecultive answers for a question, but never consecultive questions

Comment: in this case, I should have 2 answers for the same question(different rows) and in a next step, I would treat this "duplicate" by concateneting the 2 answers and remove the secon row

Answer (score 1):

If questions and answers **always** properly interleave in a user's conversation, then we can enumerate both series with window functions, then pivot:

```
select 
    max(case when tpMmessage = 'question' then timestamp end) ts_question,
    max(case when tpMmessage = 'answer'   then timestamp end) ts_answer,
    conversationId
    userId, 
    max(case when tpMmessage = 'question' then message end) question,
    max(case when tpMmessage = 'answer'   then message end) answer,
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by userId, conversationId order by timestamp) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by userId, conversationId, rn
```

If there may be gaps or islands in questions or answers, then this won't work. Here is an approach that brings the first answer to each question (if any), using window functions:

```
select 
    timestamp ts_question,
    case when lead_tp = 'answer' then lead_timestamp end ts_answer,
    conversationId,
    userId,
    message question,
    case when lead_tp = 'answer' then lead_message end answer
from (
    select t.*, 
        lead(tpMessage) over(partition by userId, conversationId order by timestamp) lead_tp,
        lead(timestamp) over(partition by userId, conversationId order by timestamp) lead_timestamp,
        lead(message) over(partition by userId, conversationId order by timestamp) lead_message,
    from mytable t
) t
where tpMessage = 'question'
```

Comment: I'm testing your 2nd block of code, the first one gave me basically the same thing I was getting null values when the case couldn't find the value.
regarding this second, what if I have more than one answer?

Comment: for example
What's your name?(row 1)
Bill(row 2)
Russel(row 3)
and then, a new question in row 4